# How can you reach a PictureBox from another method?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, static

To make my question as short as possible, this is my code. I wrote down the error I got in it.

```
public partial class VH : Form
{
    public VH()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //I can reach the pictureBox1 from here, but that's not what I want.
    }

    public static List<PictureBox> listPB;

    public static bool mV()
    {
        bool Test = true;

        listPB = new List<PictureBox>();
        listPB.Add(pictureBox1);  // <--- ERROR: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '...pictureBox1'

        return Test;
    }
```

I understand that I have to make the `PictureBox` static or available in some way but I don't know how.

Comment: Your list of picture boxes likely shouldn't be public or static.  The controls of a Form should be internal implementation details of that form; it should not be exposing them publicly.  Without knowing more about what you're actually trying to do, we can't really help you come up with a better design.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that picturebox1 is a control on VH that you added in the designer.

Now to your code "static" means that the function, variable or whatever else can be marked as static is not bound to an instance of your class.

So at the moment the call VH.listPB or VH.mV() from another class would be absolutly valid and because of that you get your error.
picturebox1 is not static, it needs an instace of VH but mV() could be called without an underlying instace of VH.

```
    public bool mV()
    {
        bool Test = true;
        listPB = new List<PictureBox>();
        listPB.Add(pictureBox1);

        return Test;
    }
```

Without the static the code is valid although not very useful.

Comment: I could not have said it better.